# Git ignore all files in a directory and subdirectories without ignoring the folders themselves

Tags: git, gitignore, api-design

I'm creating an API with a directory to store data. Within the directory there are subdirectories like `.data/customers` and `.data/transactions`. Within these subfolders are `.json` files to store data.

I want to maintain the structure of the directories while ignoring the `.json` files.

Currently, my `.gitignore` file looks like this `.data/**/*.json` but this ignores all of the directories as well as the files.

How can I setup my .gitignore to only ignore the files?

Answer (score -1):

I put a `.gitignore` file in each subdirectory with `*.json` and that gave the desired result. I wish there was a more elegant way to do this.